# How to allow self-signed certificates from a specific domain during a Maven build?

Tags: maven, ssl

My company's project requires SSL certificates from our internal company domain. Typically what we do with these self-signed certificates is to export a certificate from a web browser (e.g. Chrome), then we import these certificates into a JVM truststore (cacerts) and we reference the path to this truststore when running a maven build. E.g. by passing the following argument:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Users/joebloggs/cacerts
```

Recently I found out that there is also an option for maven to allow self signed certificates if we set the following parameters:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

I haven't asked anyone in my team why they don't use these the parameters above but I'm 100% sure this is related to security.

I would like to know if it is possible to let maven accept self-signed certificated but only from specific domains.

As an example, we have the following repositories:

- primary-nexus.JoeBloggsCompany.com
- secondary-nexus.JoeBloggsCompany.com

Is there a way for me to accept self-signed certificates only from the company domain (JoeBloggsCompany.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are assigned to physical entities (persons or hosts). The host behind the domain *JoeBloggsCompany.com* is most probably the company's WWW-server.

See [Maven Wagon HTTP, Features](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/#Features):

> - `maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall` = `true`/`false` (`false` by default), whether to match the server's X.509 certificate against a requested IP/DNS name. If false/unset, a regular server check will be used, which means that the server's IP/DNS must match either the first CN, the Subject field or one of the Subject Alternative Name extension values (in case Subject or SAN type is either `dNSName` or `iPAddress` - see [RFC 5280 for more details](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280)). Otherwise, no such matching will be applied.